# Multiple directories update with changing user permissons

Tags: unix, freebsd, patch-management, permissions

I have multiple users on one machine with FreeBSD7.3. Each user has his own site (only one). Each site is a copy of master-site with slight differences (ie. database configuration, template files).
It's like many Wordpresses with different users on one machine.

The problem is:
I've made a patch for master-site. How i can update all of this sites at once, rightly changing user permissions and ownership.

IE:  I have patch like it:

> /temp/patch/www/
>   --index.php
>   --includes/system.php

And i have many users with the same directory structure and few other files:

> /home/mike/www/mikebestsite.com/
>   --index.php
>   --index2.php
>   --includes/system.php
>
> /home/john/www/superjohnsite.com/
>   --index.php
>   --includes/system.php
>   --includes/break.php
>
> /home/larry/www/larry-e-king.com/
>   --index.php
>   --includes/system.php
>   --css/larry.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick bash snippet that should do the trick for you.

I'm making an assumption that everything in `/home` that is a directory and matches `*\.com` is a site where you want to replace `index.php` and `includes/system.php`.  If this logic is not suitable, you might have to make some modifications yourself.

I have tested it within limited constraints.  Make sure that the `ls -ld` output in FreeBSD has the user in the third field and the group in the forth field.  Also, `--reply=yes` is a GNUism.  You might have to use `-f` or the BSD equivalent to force replacement of an existing file without interaction.

```
for D in `find /home -type d -name '*\.com'`
   do
     myuser=`ls -ld $D | awk '{print $3}'`
     mygroup=`ls -ld $D | awk '{print $4}'`

     echo "Updating ${D}..."
     cp ${D}/index.php ${D}/index.php.ORIG
     cp ${D}/includes/system.php ${D}/includes/system.php.ORIG
     cp --reply=yes /path/to/temp/patch/www/index.php ${D}
     cp --reply=yes /path/to/temp/patch/www/includes/system.php ${D}/includes
     chown $myuser:$mygroup ${D}/index.php
     chown $myuser:$mygroup ${D}/includes/system.php
     echo "--------------------------------"
     echo ""
done
```

Comment: Brilliant!
Delightfully!
Magnificently!